# XML error: data at root level is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am getting this error:

> Data at the root level is invalid.
>   Line 1, position 1.

Here's my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

foreach (string c in colorList)
{
    doc.LoadXml("http://whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=" +
        c + "&username=user&password=pass");
    textBox1.Text += doc.SelectSingleNode(
        "/WhoisRecord/registrant/email").InnerText + ",";
}
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this exception?

I've tried to run the URL in the browser without any problems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `doc.Load("http:...")`
`LoadXml` is for XML strings, not URLs